# how to buffer data from CSV file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, buffer

i have CSV file `" 3000 raw"`   need to divided it to chunks but need to buffer firstly

steps in details

- read   raw by raw in buffer until reach to 1000 raw then will be chunk1
- do processes on chunk1
- delete  1000 from buffer

i don't know  how putting data "row by row" in buffer  in matlab

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Version 1

Reading the file line-by-line.

```
buffer_size = 1000;
buffer = strings([buffer_size,1]);

filename = fullfile(pwd, 'table.csv');
file_id = fopen(filename);

buffer_index = 1;
next_line = fgetl(file_id);

while(ischar(next_line))

    % Put next line into buffer.
    buffer(buffer_index) = next_line;

    % Is the buffer full?
    if buffer_index == buffer_size
        % Process buffer
        disp(buffer);

        % Clear the buffer.
        buffer = strings([buffer_size,1]);
    end

    % Advance to next line.
    buffer_index = buffer_index + 1;

    % Wrap around to start of buffer if necessary and adjust for one-based indexing.
    buffer_index = mod((buffer_index - 1), buffer_size) + 1; 

    % Read next line from file.
    next_line = fgetl(file_id);
end

fclose(file_id);
```

## Version 2

Convert the CSV file to XLSB (fast binary format XLSX) to take of advantage of [readtable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), then you can do this:

```
chunks = 3;
chunk_size = 1000;
first_column = 'A';
last_column = 'Z';

my_filename = fullfile(pwd, 'MyCsvTable.xlsb');

for chunk = 1:chunks
    chunk_begin = (chunk - 1) * chunk_size + 1;
    chunk_end = chunk_begin + chunk_size - 1;
    range = sprintf("%s%d:%s%d", first_column, chunk_begin, last_column, chunk_end);
    my_table_chunk = readtable(my_filename, 'ReadVariableNames', false, 'Range', range)

    % Process my_table_chunk

end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i want to read data as stream means without range line by line as in real stream  like sensors not as static file as steps

Comment: thanks so much i wrote another question to explain all problem as stream to be more clear why need both bufer and data chunk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147842/read-data-from-file-as-stream-in-matlab

Comment: The buffer size is 1000. Eventually the buffer_index will increment to 1001, so we need to warp around to the start, i.e. buffer_index = 1. You could replace it with an `if` conditional test.